# Casting std::vector<std::string> to void*

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, casting

I'm trying to pass in a `std::vector<std::string>` to a `void*` for use in a callback function which requires a `void*` to be passed to it. The callback is a `sqlite_exec` callback. However, I am getting a segfault when casting `vec` to a `void*`. So how can I pass in a `std::vector<std::string>` into such a callback?

```
static int cb_vector(void* vec, int argc, char**argv, char**colNm){
    std::vector<std::string>* myvec = (std::vector<std::string>*)vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        myvec->push_back(argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

std::vector<std::string> myfunc(){
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(_db, SQL, cb_vector, (void*)&vec, NULL);
    return vec;
}
```

I have already looked the following resources, but they did not answer my quesion.

- [Converting (void*) to std::vector<unsigned char>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725040/converting-void-to-stdvectorunsigned-char)
- [Passing a vector to a function as void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825274/passing-a-vector-to-a-function-as-void-pointer)

Comment: But your code is already doing it correctly. If that doesn't work, then you have to explain what's wrong with it first.

Comment: Are you getting an error or unexpected result?

Comment: You should ensure that `vec` still is in scope when the callback function is called. Otherwise I can't see what's problematic with your code.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `vec` remains in scope, because the callback is called when `sqlite3_exec` runs. @eduffy I am getting seg fault on the casting of the `vec` to `void*`

Comment: @HSchmale you are not getting segfault on that cast, it is a syntactic statement there is no action. And you better use C++ cast rather than C one, and you do not need to cast &vec to `void *`

Comment: Look into `vec.data()`. I'm not sure that'll work though since the element type is `std::string` rather than `const char*`. It might be easier to work directly with dynamic arrays here (ie, using the `new` operator and so forth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `void *` specially designed to accept pointer to any data, so your explicit cast to it is not necessary. Second - you better use C++ cast in C++ code:

```
std::vector<std::string>* myvec = static_cast<std::vector<std::string>*>( vec );
```

At least it is easier to catch problems later when you use keyword for your cast.

According to [sqlite3_exec](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) documentation:

> The 3rd argument to the sqlite3_exec() callback is an array of
>   pointers to strings obtained as if from sqlite3_column_text(), one for
>   each column. If an element of a result row is NULL then the
>   corresponding string pointer for the sqlite3_exec() callback is a NULL
>   pointer.

Most probably you get `nullptr` and try to push it into `vector`. Put additional check there:

```
myvec->push_back(argv[i] ? argv[i] : std::string() );
```

or deal with it accordingly